Windows explorer very slow unless I pause Dropbox
Windows explorer is very slow unless I pause Dropbox. Like right click takes 10 second to show a list of action. After I pause Dropbox, it gets superfast. Any way to solve this? What if I set somehow low priority for dropbox.exe?

Crtainly, reduce priority with Task Manager or Process Explorer, it can do no permanent harm. However, is there some reason to leave DropBox open all the time? Or to not use the DropBox webbrowser interface?
